# Logits have the wrong shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

When I attempt to use the softmax cross entropy function, I get a ValueError saying

```
ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2).
```

The thing is that my layers are built in such a way that my logits should output only 1 value.

The shape of my logits is (5, 1) but I have no idea why there is a 5. The X for each instance is a 5x7 matrix

```py
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(1, 5, 7), name='inputs', dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(1, 1), name='outputs', dtype=tf.int32)

hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, 150)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, 50)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 1)

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
      xentropy= tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, 
                   logits=logits)
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Check the comment, and try this code.

```py
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(1, 5, 7), name='inputs', dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(1), name='outputs', dtype=tf.int32)

flattened = tf.layers.flatten(X) # shape (1,35)
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(flattened, 150) # shape (1,150)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, 50) # shape (1,50)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 1) # shape (1,1)

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
      # expects logits of shape (1,1) against labels of shape (1)
      xentropy= tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, 
                   logits=logits)
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
```

### Original

Let's think through what's going on here.

1. You create an `X` placeholder with the shape `(5,7)` (presumably (batch_size, data_size)).
2. You feed it into a hidden layer, which transforms the shape from `(batch_size, data_size)` to `(batch_size, units)` (units here is 150)
3. Likewise for the next two layers with `hidden2` and `logits`, resulting in logits having shape `(batch_size, 1)`, which is `(5, 1)` in this case
4. You're computing cross entropy between the labels and logits. The requirement for shapes here is for logits to have shape `(batch_size, num_classes)`, where each value is the weight for a particular class, and for labels to have shape `(batch_size)`, where each value is the class number for that particular sample. So this is where things go wrong for you. Your `y` has shape `(1,1)`, and TF is expecting just a tensor or shape `(5)`.

From what I'm guessing, I think you're trying to directly feed forward X as the data of a single sample (so like a `(5,7)` shaped matrix). If this is the case, you should have `X` take the shape `(1,5,7)` to signify to Tensorflow that `X` only represents one piece of data.

Comment: You were right about my 5x7 matrix representing a single data instance. My logits  end up being a 1 by 5 by 1., but I don't understand why the 5 is here. The 1 by 5 by 7 should have indicated that the 5 isn't the batch size right?

Comment: In this case, you shouldn't be directly feeding a `(1,5,7)` tensor into a dense layer. Dense expects a 2D shape. You need to first flatten its dimensions into `(1,35)` with `tf.layers.flatten(X)`

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that my layers are built in such a way that my logits should output only 1 value.

That's not true. When X is an `a X b` tensor and you do `tf.layers.dense(X, c)`, you are multiplying X by a `b X c` matrix (and bias also added of size c). So output size is `a X c`.

In your case since the first dimension of X is 5, it continues to be 5 even for logits. And your logits should be of size 5. So you are definitely doing something wrong. It is difficult to say what is without more information.